# Sequelize instance method not working?

Tags: javascript, postgresql, orm, this, sequelize.js

I'm trying to get access to the password stored in the user instance using keyword `this` and it doesn't work?

Here is the code when I'm calling it.

```
Users.find({where: {$or: [{ email: email} ,{ username: username }]}})
  .then(user => {
    if (!user) return res.status(401).send(new errors.Unauthorized('Email/Username or Password Not Found!'));

    user.authenticate(password, (err, match) => {
      if (err) return res.status(401).send(err);
      res.send(user);
    });
  })
  .catch(err => res.send(err));
```

Here is the code for my instance method.

```
    instanceMethods :{
      authenticate: (password, cb) => {
        return bcrypt.compare(password, this.password, (err, match) => {
          if (err) return cb(new errors.Unauthorized());
          return cb(null, match);
        });
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You use arrow function, which doesn't let `this` to be bound via `call()` or `apply()`. See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#No_binding_of_this):

> Since this is not bound in arrow functions, the methods call() or apply() can only pass in parameters. this is ignored.

And further,

> As stated previously, arrow function expressions are best suited for non-method functions...

See this github issue as well https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/5858

> There is no way to override the scope of arrow functions - that's one of their main features. So there's nothing we can do here